# How do you handle duplicate answers?

Tags: discussion, new-users

A new user posted an answer to an old question that is basically a duplicate of another answer

- First response: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/7541/142
- Newer, duplicate: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/10758/142

Since this is a new user, the user does not yet have enough reputation to vote for the original answer, which would be the ideal outcome. How should the community handle this? 
Should it be flagged with an explanatory comment? Just downvote it? Or leave it alone?

Answer (score 2):

don't downvote, flag it for duplication. Mods can merge questions, and the answers follow

Comment: Ah, ok. I see it has since been deleted.